# highchart connect nulls only when two values are close (aka by distance)

Tags: highcharts, mako

I have a line chart with daily data and I want the nulls to be connected only in the case that the nulls span a day or two, not if there's a gap of weeks. know highchart has a function connectnull but I'm having trouble programming it to work only for short gaps in data. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single property for such functionality. You can for example filter your data and remove null points which are located in small intervals. For example:

```
const filteredData = data.filter((dataEl, index) => {
    const prevPoint = data[index - 1];
    const nextPoint = data[index + 1];

    if (!dataEl[1] && prevPoint && nextPoint) {
        return nextPoint[0] - prevPoint[0] > 2;
    }
    return true;
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/akrtuLh1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data